# Exclude groups in office 365 users search PowerApps

Tags: office-365, filter, groups, azure-ad, powerapps-canvas

I am creating a people picker in the PowerApps using Office365Users connection. I am able to filter the users using the below format.

```
Filter(Office365Users.SearchUser(
{searchTerm:cmb_Office365User.SearchText,top:999}), AccountEnabled=true && Not("#EXT#" in UserPrincipalName))
```

But I want to exclude the Groups and display only user results for the search. Any pointers or help would be highly appreciated.